# $\sqrt{x^2+12y}+\sqrt{y^2+12x}=33$ subject to $x+y=23$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, radicals

> Solve the system of equations:
> $\sqrt{x^2+12y}+\sqrt{y^2+12x}=33$, $x+y=23$

The obvious way to solve it is by substituting for one variable. However I was looking for a more clever solution and went ahead and plotted two graphs.

[image: graph1]

[image: graph2]

The first graph looks pretty weird so please help as to how to proceed with this graphically or an easier algebraic method.
Thanks :)

Comment: Try this https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hxnn6hcshh

Comment: To check work: the solutions are $\{x,y\}=\{10,13\}$.

Comment: Wait what. Looks like I made some mistake in graphing. I'll check and edit. Thanks

Comment: I have used your graph in the edit. Hope that's okay

Comment: For the first equation, it might be helpful to notice that exchanging the x's and y's has no effect.  That is, if you flip the graph over the y=x line, it will look exactly the same.

Comment: @Ginger feel free

Comment: Good question, etiquette for asking for the graph good, +1. As for the question itself, the problem is that I can't really make a head or tail out of the loci of the first equation, it just looks arbitrary. Substitution then seems natural, because that first equation is too rigid to transform into anything useful.

Comment: You can easy rotate the problem by 45 degrees by doing $x = u-v, y=u+v$ which immediately gives you $u=23/2$.  Then just substitute that, square twice, done.

Answer (score 5):

Don't rush to square equations to get rid of square roots.  It's almost always more work and you end up missing opportunities for simplification.  Instead eliminate square roots by substitution.  Here, let $a\ge0$ and $b\ge0$ be the values of the two square roots:

$$
\begin{cases}
x+y=23\\
a+b=33\\
a^2 = x^2 + 12y\\
b^2 = y^2 + 12x
\end{cases}
$$

While this turns your two equations into four equations, it makes simplifications easier to spot.  Subtracting the last two equations will let you factor $a^2 - b^2$ and $x^2 - y^2$ and make use of the fact that $x+y$ and $a+b$ are known:
$$33(a-b) = 23(x-y) - 12(x-y)$$
$$3(a-b) = x-y$$

Now this becomes very simple.  Let $z = a-b$ and solve for $z$.   For example, express $x$, $y$, $a$ in terms of $z$ and substitute into $(a-x)(a+x) = 12y$.  Everything will neatly cancel out and you will get $z^2 = 1$ or $a=b\pm1$ and $x=y\pm3$.  The two solutions are $x=10, y=13$ and $x=13,y=10$

Comment: good answer, wish it had more upvotes

Comment: +1 for elegance even though I fundamentally disagree with your approach re "Don't rush to square equations to get rid of square roots...".  In my opinion, it depends on the result of squaring the equations.  In my answer, the result was a quadratic in $x$ (rather than a higher degree polynomial).  Therefore, I considered the situation as *game over* and saw no need for a more elegant approach.  The issue is whether, in general, one would advise as a first step, your approach or mine.  If the solver is *new*, validly implementing creative elegance, without confusion, can be problematic.

Answer (score 3):

> $\sqrt{x^2+12y}+\sqrt{y^2+12x}=33$,$x+y=23$

> The obvious way to solve it is by substituting for one variable.

No, cart before the horse.  The first step is to move one of the radicals to the RHS and square both sides.  This gives:

$$(x^2 + 12y) = 1089 + (y^2 + 12x) - 66\sqrt{y^2 + 12x}.\tag1$$

At this point, there are two key factors:

- When you square both sides, you will generate an equation such that some of its solutions may not satisfy the original equation.
- You are looking for some elegant way of utilizing that $(x + y) = 23.$

I experimented with various tries and then decided on the following:

- $(x^2 + 12y) = x^2 + 12[23 - x] = x^2 - 12x + 276.$
- $(y^2 + 12x) = [23-x]^2 + 12x = 529 - 46x + x^2 + 12x = x^2 - 34x + 529.$

Therefore, equation (1) above simplifies to

$$(x^2 - 12x + 276) = 1089 + (x^2 - 34x + 529) - 66\sqrt{x^2 - 34x + 529} \implies $$

$$(1342 - 22x) = 66\sqrt{x^2 - 34x + 529} \implies $$

$$(61 - x) = 3\sqrt{x^2 - 34x + 529} \implies $$

$$x^2 - 122x + 3721 = 9[x^2 - 34x + 529] \implies $$

$$(8x^2 - 184x + 1040) = 0 \implies$$

$$x = \left(\frac{1}{16}\right) \times
\left[184 \pm \sqrt{33856 - \left(4 \times 8 \times 1040\right)}\right]$$

$$= \left(\frac{1}{16}\right) \times
\left[184 \pm \sqrt{576}\right]$$

$$= \left(\frac{1}{16}\right) \times
\left[184 \pm 24\right] \implies x \in \{10, 13\}.$$

Here, you have to check each **candidate** value of $x$ against the original equation.  Doing so, you realize that there are in fact two solutions: $(x=10, y=13)$ and $(x = 13, y = 10).$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $\sqrt{x^2+12y}-\sqrt{y^2+12x}=1+2a$

$$\implies\sqrt{x^2+12y}=\dfrac{23+1+2a}2,\sqrt{y^2+12x}=11-a$$

$\implies11\ge a\ge-12\ \  \ \ (1)$

$$(12+a)^2-(11-a)^2=x^2-y^2-12(x-y)=(x-y)(x+y-12)$$

Replace the value of $x+y$ to find $x-y$

Consequently we find $x,y$ in terms of $a$

But we have $$x^2+12y=(12+a)^2$$

Replace the values of $x,y$ in terms of $a$ to from a quadratic equation $a$

Solve and remember $(1)$

Comment: My bad; I misinterpreted your analysis, and then left you a corresponding comment.  I now see my mistake; I deleted my original comment.

Comment: @user2661923, I in the mean time, off loaded the hint with less calculation

Answer (score 0):

$$\left(\sqrt{x^2+12y}+\sqrt{y^2+12x}\right)^2=(x+y+10)^2$$

$$\implies x^2+12y+y^2+12x+2\left(\sqrt{(x^2+12y)(y^2+12x)}\right)=x^2 + y^2 + 100+ 2xy+20x+20 y $$

$$\implies \sqrt{(x^2+12y)(y^2+12x)}=xy+4(x+y)+50 $$

$$\implies(x^2+12y)(y^2+12x)=(xy+142)^2 $$

$$\implies x^3 - \dfrac{35 x y}{3}+ y^3 - \dfrac{5041}{3}=0$$

$$ \implies (x+y)^3-3xy(x+y)-\dfrac{35 x y}{3}-\dfrac{5041}{3}=0$$

$$\implies 23^3-69xy-\dfrac{35 x y}{3}-\dfrac{5041}{3}=0$$

Finally, we have

$$\begin{cases} x+y=23 \\ xy=130 \end {cases}$$

$$\implies x=13, y=10 $$ and

$$\implies x=10, y=13.$$

Answer (score 0):

WLOG

$$\sqrt{x^2+12y}=33\cos^2t\text{ and }\sqrt{y^2+12x}=33\sin^2t$$

$$(33\cos^2t)^2-(33\sin^2t)^2=x^2-y^2-12(x-y)=(x-y)(x+y-12)$$

$$x+y=23\implies x-y=99(\cos^2t-\sin^2t)=99(2\cos^2t-1)$$

$$\implies x=99\cos^2t-38\implies y=61-99\cos^2t$$

$$\implies(33\cos^2t)^2=x^2+12y=(99\cos^2t-38)^2+12(61-99\cos^2t)$$

Let $33\cos^2t=b$  $$\implies0=b^2-33b+272=(b-16)(b-17)$$

Hope you can take it from here?

Comment: Is there a typo in your 3rd line?  Shouldn't $(x + y) = 33$ be $(x + y) = 23$?

Comment: @user2661923, Thanks for your observation

Answer (score 0):

The obvious (simple) solution is not repeated; instead we try to see the full picture.

Whenever there are radicals with polynomials of the form including $\pm$

$$ \pm \sqrt {P(x,y)}\pm \sqrt {Q(x,y)}= 1, $$

a higher degree polynomial *should be recognized* whose factors/ equations/constituents appear separately. They can  be graphed separately as below with different colors and labels of each part. $x\pm y=0$ lines and an asymptote are drawn included for reference:

[image]

EDIT1:

Continuous segments can be shown graphed together (it can be plotted in `desmos`as well) in `Mathematica`.

```
ContourPlot[{(Sqrt[x^2 + 12 y] +Sqrt[y^2 + 12 x] +33) *
    (Sqrt[x^2 + 12 y] -Sqrt[y^2 + 12 x] +33)*
    (-Sqrt[x^2 + 12 y] +Sqrt[y^2 + 12 x] +33)*
    (+Sqrt[x^2 + 12 y] +Sqrt[
       y^2 + 12 x] -33)*(+Sqrt[x^2 + 12 y] -Sqrt[y^2 + 12 x] -33)
    (+Sqrt[x^2 + 12 y] -Sqrt[y^2 + 12 x] -33) == 0
  }, {x, -p, p}, {y, -p, p}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 ContourStyle -> {Thick, Red}]
```

Six factors and a product polynomial plot with uncut segments are shown.

[image]

A neat rational ***cubic*** product polynomial equation is cumbersome and unless seen in that form I feel as having not taken to the finish. A symmetric graph with respect to y-axis could be obtained by $45^{\circ}$ CW rotation.

Comment: How can you know these graphs without a graphing calculator? I had never seen them before.

Comment: OK, you want to obtain the solutions$\; (x,y)= (10,13),(13,10)$ analytically ?

Comment: I was just wondering if that was possible without taking any help of a graphing calculator.

Comment: I am quite sure it is possible, but could be cumbersome.